# How do I make axios in NodeJS work the same way as requests from Python?

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping, cookies, request

I am attempting to obtain essential cookies for future use as a registered user of the toloka.to website by making a POST request to https://toloka.to/login.php with all necessary body parameters.

In Python it just works, I get plain html where I can check that the page contains elements for logged-in users, and in cookies I can see something like that:

```
{'toloka_1218067_tt': '1708023715', 'toloka_1218067_f': 'a%3A0%3A%7B%7D', 'toloka_1218067_uf': '0', 'toloka_1218067_u': 'a%3A0%3A%7B%7D'}
```

In NodeJS I get this:

```
['toloka_data=a%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A11%3A%22autologinid%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22userid%22%3Bi%3A-1%3B%7D; expires=Fri, 14-Feb-2025 19:29:42 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; secure; httponly',
      'toloka_sid=c4ab745ccad638caadda384685c38e36; path=/; secure; httponly',
      'toloka___lastvisit=1708025382; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-1971 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=-1676489382; path=/; secure',
      'toloka___tt=1708025382; expires=Fri, 14-Feb-2025 19:29:42 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; secure',
      'toloka___f=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D; expires=Fri, 14-Feb-2025 19:29:42 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; secure',
      'toloka___uf=0; expires=Fri, 14-Feb-2025 19:29:42 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; secure',
      'toloka___u=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D; expires=Fri, 14-Feb-2025 19:29:42 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; secure']
```

I messed around with all these cookies and found out that for any future request toloka_sid is enought. If you login with any browser, delete all the cookies you have except that one, it would work. But I didn't see toloka_sid in the Python cookies, and on top of that it works without it, when in NodeJS all these cookies are just not valid, including toloka_sid.

I also noticed that in Python most of the cookies look similar to "toloka_1218067_tt", whereas in NodeJS it looks like "toloka___tt". I tried hardcoding the numbers as in Python, replacing the second underscore with the appropriate numbers, but still no luck.

The actual code here:

- Python

```
    import requests
    
    session = requests.Session()
    
    login = session.post(
        f"https://toloka.to/login.php",
        {
            "username": "SomeUser",
            "password": "SomePassword",
            "autologin": "on",
            "ssl": "on",
            "login": "Вхід",
        },
    )
    
    print(login.cookies.get_dict())
    
    getDataWithCredential = session.get(
        f"https://toloka.to/tracker.php?nm=frieren"
    )
    
    with open('xd.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(login.text)
    
    with open('xd2.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(getDataWithCredential.text)
```

- NodeJS

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', 'SomeUser');
    formData.append('password', 'SomePassword');
    formData.append('autologin', 'on');
    formData.append('ssl', 'on');
    formData.append('login', 'Логін');
    
    const data = await axios.post('https://toloka.to/login.php', formData, { withCredentials: true });
    const cookies = data.headers['set-cookie'];
    
    console.log(cookies);
    console.log(data.data);
```

Comment: Can you provide guest credential(username, password) for logging?

Comment: You can delete that credential, I leverage it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, This node.js make same print output.
I am using `node-fetch` instead of 'Axios' library.

In your specific case, since `node-fetch` is providing the expected output, it's likely that `Axios` has some default behavior or response handling that's different from what you expect.

The differences in the output between `Axios` and `node-fetch` could be due to how each library handles responses and headers. While both libraries aim to provide similar functionality for making HTTP requests, they may have differences in their implementation details.

Each library may have its own defaults and behaviors, such as how it handle redirects, handles cookies, or parses response bodies.

node.js output

```
{
  toloka_data: 'a%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A11%3A%22autologinid%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22userid%22%3Bi%3A-1%3B%7D',
  toloka_sid: '159a8c7bc0059d2e1fc43b53bcc5ad33',
  toloka___lastvisit: '1708050186',
  toloka___tt: '1708050186',
  toloka___f: 'a%3A0%3A%7B%7D',
  toloka___uf: '0',
  toloka___u: 'a%3A0%3A%7B%7D'
}
```

[image]

Python output

```
{
  'toloka_1218067_tt': '1708049854',
  'toloka_1218067_f': 'a%3A0%3A%7B%7D',
  'toloka_1218067_uf': '0',
  'toloka_1218067_u': 'a%3A0%3A%7B%7D'
}
```

[image]

##### Node.js code

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import fs from 'fs';

const USER_NAME = 'SomeUser';
const PASSWORD = 'SomePassword';

(async () => {
  try {
    const loginResponse = await fetch('https://toloka.to/login.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: `username=${USER_NAME}&password=${PASSWORD}&autologin=on&ssl=on&login=Вхід`
    });

    const cookies = loginResponse.headers.raw()['set-cookie'];
    const cookieDict = {};

    cookies.forEach(cookie => {
      const [keyValuePair] = cookie.split(';');
      const [key, value] = keyValuePair.split('=');
      cookieDict[key] = value;
    });

    console.log(cookieDict);

    // Write the login response to a file
    const loginData = await loginResponse.text();
    fs.writeFileSync('xd.html', loginData, { encoding: 'utf-8' });

    // Fetch data with credentials
    const getDataWithCredentialResponse = await fetch('https://toloka.to/tracker.php?nm=frieren');

    // Write the data with credentials response to another file
    const dataWithCredential = await getDataWithCredentialResponse.text();
    fs.writeFileSync('xd2.html', dataWithCredential, { encoding: 'utf-8' });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  }
})();
```

xd.html almost similar but not same
Left is Python/ right is node.js
compare by WinMerge

[image]

xd2.html compare too
Left is Python/ right is node.js
[image]

Comment: Thank you for diving so deeply into my problem. I really appreciate it. But unfortunately in behave the same as I stated. I really should have given you a way to determine that cookies are valid because of the language barrier and you don't really understand what you're getting. I'll upload examples of xd1.html for both variants. 

Here: [python](https://pastebin.com/i2e0i71J), [NodeJS](https://pastebin.com/QbdHvTcx)

Comment: Basically, if the login was successful, you should see the nickname you provided in the response html, in our scenario it would be "TolokaChan". Or even just judging by it's length, the right one should be much bigger.

I also don't really understand why your Python example gave the same output, but in the examples above I used my Python script because you didn't provide yours. And your NodeJS variant just to be sure.

Comment: Also, to see if these credentials are valid for future requests, such as output for xd2.html, the table it generates shouldn't be empty. That one request we used should have 4 entries. Here is another example of a correct response: [xd2.html (Python)](https://pastebin.com/K0KREGj0).

I really hope this helps. Only if we could somehow communicate in real time, so I could show you clearly what's happening, it would be much easier to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to recreate the same behaviour using CookieJar and wrapped it all in my own axios client.
Here is my solution as a separate module:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { CookieJar } from 'tough-cookie';
import { wrapper } from 'axios-cookiejar-support';

const axiosWithCookies = () => {
    const jar = new CookieJar();

    const client = wrapper(axios.create({ jar }));

    const getCookies = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            jar.getCookies('https://toloka.to/', (err, cookies) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(cookies);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    const resetCookies = () => {
        jar.removeAllCookies(err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error clearing cookies:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Cookies cleared successfully');
            }
        });
    };

    return { client, getCookies, resetCookies };
}

export default axiosWithCookies;
```

Example usage:

```
import axiosWithCookies from './axiosSession.js';

const { client, getCookies, resetCookies } = axiosWithCookies();

const getLoginCredentials = async (username = process.env.TOLOKA_LOGIN, password = process.env.TOLOKA_PASSWORD) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', username);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('autologin', 'on');
    formData.append('ssl', 'on');
    formData.append('login', 'Вхід');

    const res = await client.post('https://toloka.to/login.php', formData, { withCredentials: true });

    if (!res.data.includes(username)) return;

    const cookies = await getCookies();

    resetCookies();

    return cookies.map(cookie => `${cookie.key}=${cookie.value}`).join('; ');
}
```